# Best way to exclude object from search with Fluent NHibernate Search

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-interface, nhibernate.search

I have a class with a boolean property.

I want to exclude instance with a false value from search result.

What is the best way to do that with Fluent NHibernate Search ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 3 ways of doing that

1. exclude instance from being store in the lucene index
2. using full text filter ([more here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html/search-mapping.html#d0e3099))
3. "kind of where clause" using Lucene Query

Using full text filter seems to be the best solution. Unfortunately, it's not implemented in Fluent Nhibernate Search. I found a hack and hope to be able to contribute adding this feature.